# Llamado de rutas de archivos php

Tags: php

digamos tengo components/conductor/edit.php y si en el archivo edit requiero o incluyo un archivo con su ruta no lo encuentra sea cual sea la manera es decir ../../includes/sidebar.php o ./includes/sidebar.php, pero si paso ese edit a la carpeta padre components/edit.php si encuentra el archivo con la ruta ../includes/sidebar.php. Alguien sabe por que es asi? como ubico el archivo dentro de conductor y no fuera de el, en la imagen pues se observa donde estoy ubicado abajo de la pestaña de la ventada y al costado izquierdo lo que quiero traer.  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes probar mejor usar rutas completas haciendo uso de la constante ____FILE____ y dirname(), en tu caso podrías buscar usar en components/conductor/edit.php include_once(dirname(dirname(____FILE____)).'/includes/sidebar.php'); el editor no me deja escribir la constante bien pero es con dos guiones bajos antes y después de la palabra FILE

Comment: @Tabitha Para evitar el uso de ````__FILE__```` y ````dirname()```` puedes utilizar directamente ````__DIR__```` que te proporcionará una sintaxis más limpia para obtener el directorio actual del archivo.

Comment: @Tabitha si encuentra la direccion como la pusiste, pero sigue sin traerme lo que necesito, y pues si eso me descuadra mucho el proyecto, alguna idea de que pueda ser?

Comment: Agregue una imagen de como estan los directorios

Comment: Puedes agregarle otro dirname para subir otro directorio, también intenta imprimir la ruta que te sale antes de hacer el include para que puedas debugearla mejor

Comment: Segui tu consejo de imprimir que rutas me daba los dir, y di bien con la dirreccion, pero al momento de cargar el componente, no carga la pagina y miro la consola de la pagina y me manda "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)", aqui la imagen de las rutas, https://ibb.co/0ZLr9b5 y la imagen de lo que me manda el server  https://ibb.co/h73QG8k